# Another Unity3D rotation question: restricting a rotation to be within a range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

thanks in advance for your attention with my very simple question! Dealing with rotation in Unity3D seems to be something I'm perpetually rusty with. What I'm trying to do is to lock an objects X rotation to be at most positive 40 degrees, and at least -30 degrees. This seems simple enough because in the editor, I can clearly see on the object's transform when there has been a 40 or -30 degree rotation, but in my script it seems much more difficult to tell if it's been rotated. Here's a screenshot of my simple object hierarchy, the object I'm concerned with rotating is `Camera Pivot`:

[image: Editor object hierarchy screenshot]

The script that I'm doing this from is mounted on the `Player` object, and here is the code I started with (which I know is obviously wrong, but hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to get at):

```
private void ProcessMouseInput()
    {
        float horizontal = mouseSensitivity * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float vertical = -(mouseSensitivity * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        transform.Rotate(0, horizontal, 0);
        cameraPivot.Rotate(vertical, 0, 0);

        if (cameraPivot.rotation.x < cameraPitchFloor) cameraPivot.rotation = new Quaternion(cameraPitchFloor, 0, 0, 0);
        if (cameraPivot.rotation.x > cameraPitchCeiling) cameraPivot.rotation = new Quaternion(cameraPitchCeiling, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

This is called in the `Update()` method, and both `cameraPitchFloor` and `cameraPitchCeiling` are declared at the top of the file as floats with values `-30f` and `40f`, respectively.

I know that the `Transform.rotation` gets a Quaternion, which is not the information I'm really looking for there. I suppose my final question would be how do I access those values in degrees that I'm seeing in the inspector, the "Local rotation of this GameObject relative to the parent"? `Transform.eulerAngles` or `.localEulerAngles` don't seem to do the trick either because this won't give a "negative" rotation, but the corresponding "positive" rotation that would end up at the same place, which isn't useful because how would I then be able to tell if I should be resetting the rotation to be the "lowest" point or the "highest" point? Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 0):

cameraPivot.rotation returns a quaternion. What you see in the editor is euler angles. Replace the last 2 lines with

```
if (cameraPivot.rotation.eulerAngles.x < cameraPitchFloor) cameraPivot.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(cameraPitchFloor, 0, 0);
if (cameraPivot.rotation.eulerAngles.x > cameraPitchCeiling) cameraPivot.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(cameraPitchCeiling, 0, 0);
```